# How does deconstructing vehicles work?

Tags: planetside-2

I've heard that it's possible to deconstruct vehicles, but I've never done it. How do you do that? What does deconstructing them do?

Comment: Accessible through vehicle menu, and it gives you some of the resources back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deconstructing vehicles is no longer possible. In mid-March, a hotfix removed the functionality of the "Deconstruct" button, and [the March 27 patch removed the button from the UI entirely.](http://wiki.planetside-universe.com/ps/Game_Update_%282013/03/27%29)

Answer (score 7):

Deconstruct just removes your vehicle. This prevent enemy's from getting point by destroying it.

Killing a flash should give 25 XP and by deconstructing it you can prevent the enemy from getting that XP. Now Flash isnt that big of a deal but other vehicles can cost a fortune.

Deconstructing does **NOT** reset or lower the cooldown and also [does not return any resources](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hm1XUNIn2sI).

Some people **abuse** this option to prevent XP from being rewarded... when you shoot a galaxy for example (300 XP) and it almost dies, people deconstruct it fast and prevents the enemy from destroying it and will not receive 300 XP.

You can decontruct in the same menu as you can lock your vehicle...

Default button : **Page Down**

Comment: Its also useful if you are sneaking in to avoid tipping the enemy off that you might be nearby.

Comment: @Justin Indeed. I spy a little spy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use deconstucting in a sneaky way. I.E. you could fill a Galaxy with a squad and then deconstruct the Galaxy so the enemy won't know there are enemies in the place.

If the enemy knows you're already there, you could deconstruct the Galaxy so they can't get XP.

The Default button is page down. You can change this by going to keybindings and selecting air.